# how to compare accuracy of the output of 2 nn trained with different perform functions

Tags: regression, neural-networks, model-evaluation

Let's say I have 2 equal FFNN trained with the same data (multidimensional data, n>10), except that one uses mse as perfFcn and the other use sse.

If t is the target data, t1 and t2 are the output of each network. How can I compare t1 and t2 (so I can choose one network over the other). I was thinking of relative error:||t-ti||/||t|| but I'm not really sure.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between sum of squares (SSE) and mean squared error (MSE) is the division by the dataset size:

MSE = SSE/n, where n is dataset length (or batch size)

So there is no qualitative difference between the loss functions, since the relationship is linear. Each optimum for MSE is also the optimum for SSE.

So in order to compare your models you can use MSE or SSE and you will get the same result. MSE is better for comparing because it takes the dataset length into account, but if you use the same test dataset it does not matter.

If you use NNs i would recommend MSE, because SSE messes with the learning rate for batch sizes larger then 1. MSE on the other hand scales the loss independent of the batch size.

Comment: What about sae, mae and crossentropy?

Comment: SAE and MAE are identical, except for the normalization. Cross Entropy is a different metric.

Comment: then, how can i compare nn trained with mse and crossentropy?